# apply CSS dynamically in asp.net 2.0

Tags: css, asp.net-2.0, dynamic-css

I have a scrolling div with Three linkbuttons and three differents divs. I need to apply CSS to active linkbutton  as soon as button is clicked.The codes used by me are:

```
protected void btnNetwork_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.btnForecast.CssClass = "li_1";
        this.btnBlog.CssClass = "li_2";
        this.btnNetwork.CssClass = "li_3_active";
        this.btnNetwork.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
        lblMsg.Visible = false;
        BindGW("-----------------------------------");
        Forecast.Visible = false;
        Blog.Visible = false;
        Network.Visible = true;
    }
```

Thanks & Regards,

Khushi

Comment: So what's the question? Is the above not working for you?

Comment: You are polluting a client side question with server side code.  Would be much better to post the HTML of the link button as it is rendered and explain how you would like that changed when the button is clicked.

Comment: Kill this question and open another one the down votes mean you will never get an answer.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using server side event use client side javascript event. Try:

```
$get('btnId').setAttribute("class", "some_class_name");
```

Answer (score 1):

You will not be able to dynamically change the CSS properties of elements by using post-back, which refreshes the page. Javascript must be used if you want to the change to happen immediately.

Answer (score 0):

Simple example:

- take one button and one label
- create one stylesheet and add class style1 as:

```
body 
{   
}

.style1
{
  color: #000080;
}
```

- write this simple code in button click event

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  this.Label1.CssClass = "style1";
}
```